# Why didn't Minato's shroud change when he used Tailed Beast Mode?

Tags: naruto

**Naruto's Nine Tails Chakra Mode**:
[image]

**Naruto's Tailed Beast Mode**:

[image]

The change in the appearance is very clear.

**Minato**

[image]

Minato's Nine Tails Chakra Mode and Tailed Beast Mode (when he can use Kurama avatar) appearance remains the same. Only his pupils change. So why didn't his shroud get a new design like Naruto's?

Comment: try to add chapter, episode or pic so that we get to know what you actually trying to say.

Comment: Did that help undertand better my question?

Comment: I don't think we actually get to see Minato's chakra mode. Can you post an episode, image, etc. of it?

Comment: since Naruto is controlling the chakra and he admires his dad as a hokage and wants to assume a more alike appearance, he unconsciously transforms the chackra to that shape. in boruto we see that the kurama mode just like minato there is no change is the shape.

Answer (score 2):

According to [the wiki](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Nine-Tails_Chakra_Mode), the difference between "Nine-tails Chakra Mode" and "Kurama Mode", the one you called "Tailed Beast Mode" is simply that Naruto learned Kyuubi's name: Kurama. At that point, Kurama wasn't just lending Naruto chakra, they were fighting together.

I would guess that Minato never learned to fight together with Kurama or ALWAYS fought together with it, so Kurama never changed Minato's appearance.

The wiki actually defined "Tailed Beast Mode" when the Jinchuuriki assumes their tailed beast's form:

[image]

This is both Naruto and Minato in "Tailed Beast Mode" performing a combined *Rasengan*.

Comment: Kurama is a he isn't he?

Comment: I honestly don't know, I went for "she" first, then I used "it". I actually looked around a bit but found nothing definitive.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because when the nine tails was split into two halves, so was it's ability to transform into Tailed Beast Mode. Yang Kurama (the one Naruto has) has to go Kurama Mode prior to going into Tailed Beast Mode where as Yin Kurama (the one Minato has) has to go straight into Tailed Beast Mode. When both halves of Kurama are combined into the original form, they gain the ability to go into Tailed Beast Mode however they want (either straight from Nine Tails Chakra Mode or from Kurama Mode).

Answer (score 1):

I think that it's because Minato has better chakra control than naruto if you look at the pics the first version(nine tails chakra mode) he looks like he's having trouble controlling the chakra whereas in the second (tailed beast mode) one its not a problem I would assume this is because when he's in nine tails chakra mode he had to take the chakra by force from the nine tails (episode 245)and in Tailed Beast Mode they are acting more as a team (episode 500). While he might have trouble since it's commonly known that Naruto's chakra control is not too great Minato became the 4th Hokage so I would assume he has good control since I doubt he had tons of chakra he could just throw around like Naruto can so he could probably refine his without teaming up with the nine tails.  Its been a while since I watched Naruto though so this might not be totally accurate but as far as I can remember this would explain the difference.

Answer (score 1):

This is because he already has a cloak. The shroud of chakra forms as a cloak and it can't do that if there's already a cloak to begin with.

Think about it, everytime they have a cloak on the transformation hasn't changed them.

The chakra can't make it's own form so it just ends up raping itself around what's already there.